# Does a Matroid's graph not having 3-separation mean its dual doesn't have 3-separation?

Tags: graph-theory, matroids

Let there be a graph $G$, with a matroid $M(G)$. If there is no 3-separation in $M$, does it imply there isn't one in $M^*$?

Any hints would be much appriciated!